# What would be the easiest way to explore the Rally object models?

Tags: javascript, json, rally

I am required to develop a view for the Rally agile tool using Javascript and HTML. I have not dealt with web languages that often in my new career as a dev.

I am just exploring their API, but am lost in how to explore their available object model, specifically, what can I query. I am not strong enough in JS to guess. I'd like to find something that shows what I can query, the objects, their properties, etc.

Do any of you have a link or someway to explore what is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get started by looking at the [AppSDK](http://dev.developer.rallydev.com/app-sdk). It is a toolkit that will help you make customized html + js views of Rally data in a simplified manner.

If you want to see the documentation on our Object Model you can look [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/).

Feel free to ask questions on here we try to do out best to be of assistance in our free time.

Comment: Much thanks. I was in the API, but didn't scroll down far enough. I feel like an imbecile. That was much help. Querying data as we speak.